# Why it doesn't solve this?

Tags: nonlinear, education

Why Mathematica gives me an empty brackets {} when I ask it to solve this equation?

```
Solve[29.6793984 + 3.213378*b + 1.606689*Sqrt[1 - 4*b^2] == 0, b]
```

Comment: `{}` means there are no solutions.

Comment: [Have you tried to search before asking?](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Why+Mathematica+gives+me+empty+brackets)  I copied your words into Google literally, and the first hit is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

To see why it can't solve it, I use this trick.

First re-write in equation in symbolic form

```
(*expr=29.6793984+3.213378*b+1.606689*Sqrt[1-4*b^2];*)

expr=x+y*b+z*Sqrt[1-4*b^2];
params={x->29.6793984,y->3.213378,z->1.606689};
```

Now ask Solve to solve it, since your parameters are real, then

```
 sol=Solve[expr==0&&Element[{x,y,z},Reals],b]
```

You'll get long solutions, with conditions on `x,y,z` to satisfy.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets look at first conditions of them that show up

```
 (y>0&&2 x+y>=0&&y-2 z<0&&z>0&&2 x-y<0)
```

Then do

```
 (y>0&&2 x+y>=0&&y-2 z<0&&z>0&&2 x-y<0)/.params
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can try each one of these conditions, and you'll see your parameters do no satisfy any of them.  This is why `Solve` found no solution.

Comment: Here's another way to see: `NMinimize[Abs[29.6793984 + 3.213378*b + 1.606689*Sqrt[1 - 4*b^2]], b]` This returns {20.9249, {b -> -4.6181}}. So it can never reach zero because it's minimum is 20.9.